# Is an reflexive relation also antisymetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I've already seen a similar question here:

[Is an Anti-Symmetric Relation also Reflexive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101925/is-an-anti-symmetric-relation-also-reflexive)

But my question is rather, if you know that a relation is reflexive, then, can this relation also be antisymetric?

As far as I know, by definition, a relation is antisymetric if for two elements in *R*, *xRy* and *yRx* then *x=y*. For this to be true, I should only need *x=y* to be true for the relation to be antisymetric. In that case, the relation is antisymetric if we know it is reflexive already.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Reflexive is x=x not x=y. are you thinking of symmetric? Also your question seems confusing: Are you asking if a relation's being reflexive forces it to be antisymmetric?

Comment: Yes that's the question, sorry if it's confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflexivity does not imply anti-symmetry.

Consider a relationship defined over just $2$ elements: $a$ and $b$. And suppose that we have $aRa$, $aRb$, $bRb$, and $bRa$. Then $R$ is reflexive (since we have both $aRa$ and $bRb$), but $R$ is not anti-symmetric: we have $aRb$ and $bRa$, but it is not the case that $a = b$

Comment: I see. I didn't consider a case like this. it seems that I was "mixing" the definitions of reflexive and anti-symetric. Silly mistake. Thanks for clarifying! @Bram28

Comment: @nutshell_A You're welcome! I make silly mistakes like this all the time :P